# getting error when trying to see UI elements in UI automator viewer

Tags: android, uiautomatorviewer

I have connected samsung s7 edge with android 7 to my macbook and trying to find UI element ID's using UI automator viewer. I need element attributes  related to calling like answer call button, decline and end call button. but getting the following error

WHAT I HAVE TRIED: its working fine and i am able to see elements on other android phones like MOTO G and LENOVO vibe K5 note both have android 6.

Error i am getting:

Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: 
  com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!